# Intellij : import project as library for another project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am developing a project A (Java Maven) which uses a library B (a `JAR` file)

I have the source code of library B, and I want to change code in project B, while it's used as library for project A.

Is that possible in Intellij to replace a `JAR` library by its source code ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd configure a multi-module Maven project with the parent aggregate `pom.xml` and 2 sub-modules: for the app and for the library with their own `pom.xml` files.

Define a dependency on the `lib` module for the `app` module. IDE will resolve such dependencies via the sources and you will see the changes in the project instantly without the need to compile. Refactorings will also work across the modules so that you can rename a method from the usage in the `app` and it will automatically rename it in the `lib`.